# Line breaks not working on clarity expandable rows data grid

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity

First time I am using the expandable rows feature of Clarity datagrid. My initial assumption was, I can write any HTML inside the collapsed view to display.

VMware expandable datagrid: https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/datagrid/expandable-rows

But somehow, this is not working. Even if I explicitly mention `<br>` tag, then also line break is not happening.

```
<clr-dg-row-detail *clrIfExpanded>
    <h2> 1st Line </h2>
    <br>
    <h3> Why the next line is not coming in new Line </h3>
</clr-dg-row-detail>
```

I am not sure if I am missing some basic concept, but this is annoying, and not able to figure out how I can fix this.
Here is my stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-datagrid-basic-fvjrst?file=app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container for the expanded content uses `display: flex` which is causing your block items to flex to fit the container. The simple workaround is to wrap it in a single block element like this.

```
<clr-dg-row-detail *clrIfExpanded>
  <div>
    <h2> Header 2 </h2>
    <br>
    <h3> Header 3 </h3>
  </div>
</clr-dg-row-detail>
```

I'll investigate this further and see if we can fix it better, but this gives you a way forward.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this solved my problem to good extent, but still there are some styling challenges, but I can do some workaround to fix that.

As a side note, I really liked Clarity a lot and it has great potential to beat other available option. The only problem with clarity what I feel is, you guys are slow developing/adding new features. Overall great work guys.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, it may seem like we go slow sometimes due to the size of our team and the complexities of writing high quality components. Its very different to write a library compared to an application, and we do our best to craft the best user and developer experience, along with high standards for code quality. It does take time, but thanks for working with us!